# R: What does := operator do in R?

Tags: r, data.table, h2o

I came across this syntax while learning R and H2O, however I could not discern what

```
 :=
```

operator does in R.

Comment: This is not a base R operator. It is for the `data.table` package. Take a look at the documentation: `library(data.table); help(":=")`.

Comment: @lmo it actually is a(n undocumented) base R operator - if it wasn't `data.table` (and `ggplot2` and maybe other packages) wouldn't be able to use it as one. It just isn't used for anything in base R.